# Django ORM Search Multiple Conditional Query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a problem when I want to search my queryset with multiple conditional. In my database, the hscode saved as `"0105.14.90"`. I need to search the hscodes with following this query `"01051490"`. eg:

```
>>> query = '0105.14.90'
>>> HSCode.objects.filter(hscode=query)
<QuerySet [<HSCode: 0105.14.90>]>


>>> query = '01051490'
>>> HSCode.objects.filter(hscode=query)
<QuerySet []>
```

The bad think I can do, is look like this:

```
hscodes = []
query = '01051490'

for hscode in HSCode.objects.order_by('-id'):
    if query.isdigit() and hscode.hscode == query:
        hscodes.append(hscode)

    elif hscode.hscode.replace('.', '') == query:
        hscodes.append(hscode)
```

How can handle it with ***ORM*** only?

```
>>> query = '01051490'
>>> HSCode.objects.filter(Q(hscode=query) | Q(???))
<QuerySet [<HSCode: 0105.14.90>]>
```

Comment: is there any logic for placing dots in the query?

Comment: @ruddra nothing..

Comment: can't you strip dots then save them in DB?

Comment: try using contains or icontains: 
HSCode.objects.filter(hscode__contains = query) or HSCode.objects.filter(hscode__icontains = query)
or combine both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`Replace`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#replace).

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

query = '01051490'
HSCode.objects.annotate(
    hscode_without_dots=Replace('hscode', Value('.'), Value(''))
).filter(hscode_without_dots=query)
```

Comment: great idea, it works. btw, does it support with regex?

Comment: You mean something like `HSCode.objects.filter(hscode__regex=r'%s\.?%s\.?%s' % (query[:4], query[4:6], query[6:8]))` assuming the format is always the same.